# django 2.0 - including urls file from an app to the root urls file

Tags: python, django, url

I'm interested in have for each app their own urls.py file and then, include them in the root urls.py file using the include django function like this `include('myapp.urls')`.

Everything here follows the django tutorial: [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/)

So, in **root urls.py** it is like this:

```
from django.url import include, path
urlpatterns = [ path('folio/', include('folio.urls')) ]
```

and now in the **folio urls.py** it is like the following:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [ path('', views.home, name='home') ]
```

After some tryings all I get is page not found.

[image]

What am I missing?

There's a variation to this to work, in this case I just need to import the app to the **root urls.py** as following:

```
from django.url import path
from folio import views
urlspatterns = [ path('', views.home, name='home') ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The page error is very clear. No urls pattern is found in any of your views given your root url `'/'` or `www.example.com/`. Since your urls only include `admin/` and `folio/`. No '/' was registered.

But according to your workaround yes you must **MAP A URL TO A PARTICULAR VIEW**.

And in your case the `folio.views.home` is mapped. You might need to create a home view to render `base.html` as homepage.

**urls.py**

```
from django.url import include, path
from main.views import home # main is a master app that renders index or home page.

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name="index"),
    path('folio/', include('folio.urls'))
]
```

**app_name/views.py**

```
 def home(request):
     return render(request, 'main/base.html', {})
```

I also encourage todo an app namespacing, in your folio.urls.py before the `urlpatterns` add this `app_name = 'folio'` So you can navigate to your folio app home using this url syntax in your `main/templates/main/base.html` template.

**main/templates/main/base.html**

```
 <a href="{% url 'folio:home' %}">Go to folio home page</a>
```

Comment: Sorry for this late response. I actually solved it after some more tryings. In the root urls.py file, changing the line <code>path('folio/', include('folio.urls'))</code> to be this <code>path('', include('folio.urls'))</code> worked. And, in the folio app, its urls.py stay the same as <code>path('', home, name='home')</code>. Anyway, I'm thankfull for you time and kindness in trying to help, and for the encouragement to use an app namespacing, I'll sure be doing that.