# Issues with path() in urls.py in django 2.0.5

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do the following thing in urls.py but Django 2.0.5 doesn't seem to support url(). Instead of it, I used path() but still, its throwing invalid syntax error.
Can someone give a clearer picture of path() as it seems to be not supporting regex.

Providing the code here:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import home_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('$', home_page)
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: missing comma, at path('$', home_page)

Answer (score 1):

You miss a `,`, and `$` is unnecessary

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import home_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: I am still getting this error: File "D:\Workspace\web_dev\Environments\newenv\ecommerce\ecommerce\urls.py", line 24
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I pasted it in the previous comment.

Comment: When, I tried django 1.11 version, it worked fine with url(), but not working with path() in 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

> **Django2** has 2 functions for URLconfs, **path()**, **re_path()**.

You can use regex paths (regular expression based paths) with **re_path()**, so remove `$` and place `,` between two consecutive paths.

> **Note**: Let suppose your app name is **my_django_app** created by **python manage.py startapp my_django_app** command.

I created a new Django app named **my_django_app** and tried, it works fine. I have the following code in my **urls.py** file.

```
"""my_django_proj URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from my_django_app.views import home_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

> **References**:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/
>
> [django 2.0 - including urls file from an app to the root urls file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455151/django-2-0-including-urls-file-from-an-app-to-the-root-urls-file)

Thanks.

Comment: Let me try to create new Django app in my system and try your code. I'll get get back to you soon. Thanks.

Comment: **@Simanto**, I created new Django app and tried. Let suppose you have created your app with `python manage.py startapp my_django_app` then you will need to change the import statement 
 &raquo; **from my_django_app.views import home_page** in **urls.py**. I've also updated the answer. Please check & thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you want, you can download my app's zip from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Npip87aqNBScCYpcufxMbVzUOZmZgUV0/view?usp=sharing link and look into the code.

Comment: No problem, enjoy Django.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use **url** instead of **path**, that will work just fine. You just have to import from **django.conf.urls** instead. So your import statement should look like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

Django says on their documentation page that this feature will likely be deprecated in future versions to **re-path**, however, **url** still works fine for me, and I'm running *Django **2.0.7***... so, I imagine it would work with yours as well. I guess because of this, with Django version 2 and above, it nows decides when it creates the boilerplate project that instead of importing urls from **django.conf.urls**, it imports *path* from **django.urls**. (**Note**: PATH doesn't allow for regex)

What I typically do, is create an *app specific* **urls.py**. In that *urls.py* I'll import **url** from **django.conf.urls** and have my specific *app level urls* there:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from app_name import views # have to import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^users$',views.users),
]
```

Then in the *project level* **urls.py** I'll add the **include** module as so I can link it to my *app specific* **urls.py** file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from app_name import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^',include('app_name.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

(**Note**: If you have a separate folder in between such that the folder structure looks something like **mainproject>apps>app_name>**(settings.py, views.py, admin.py etc...) you will have to create an **__init__.py** file in the apps folder as so Django can recognize the module.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

As stated in the above answers, the `$` is unnecessary while using `path()`. You are getting a syntax error due to the comma after `admin.site.urls)` which should be removed.